# AJAX returns previous value in array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm making a website to host artwork. The idea is that when the page loads I have JavaScript run a php file that makes a query to the server to get the names and IDs of the image files (artwork.jpg) and display them as thumbnails on a page.

When you scroll over the thumbnail, the artwork is displayed larger on a different part of the screen and the description, specs, etc for the piece of art fades in. My issue is that when I make this second AJAX call it appends the value of the previously moused over image to the screen and does nothing until you've moused over at least two images.

Here's my code for the first ajax call that appends thumbnails to the page and creates a form with the value of the thumnbnail's id:

```
function getArtDescriptions()
{
    $.post('../../path/to/script/get_art.php', function(json)
    {
       if (json.art.length > 0)
        {

            $.each(json.art,function() 
            {
                    var info =  
                                 '<div class = "thumbnail_box">'
                                + '<img src = "images/thumbnails/'
                                + this['img']
                                + '"id = "'
                                + this['ID']
                                + '"> '
                                + '<form id = "art_descriptions'
                                + this['ID']
                                + '" '
                                + 'name = "art_descriptions'
                                + this['ID']
                                + '">'
                                + '<input type = "hidden" id = "descriptions" name = "descriptions" value = "'
                                + this['ID']
                                + '"></form>'
                                + '</div>';

            });

        }
        }, 'json');

}
```

And this is the code I'm using to make the second AJAX call that is giving me a problem:

```
setTimeout(function get_id()
{

    var tooltipTimeout;

    $(".thumbnail_box img").on("mouseenter", function()
    {
        tooltipTimeout = setTimeout(details(this.id),0);
        console.log(this.id);

    });
    $(".thumbnail_box img").on("mouseleave", function()
    {
        hideTooltip();
    });

function hideTooltip()
    {
        clearTimeout(tooltipTimeout);
        $(".description").fadeOut().remove();
    }
}, 800);



//GRAB DESCRIPTIONS FROM DATABASE AND 
function details(art)
{
    var formname = "#art_descriptions"+art;
    var filename = '../../file/path/to/script/get_descriptions.php';

    //console.log($(formname).serialize());

    $(".thumbnail_box img").on("mouseenter", function()
    {
        $.post(filename, $(formname).serialize(), function(json)
        {
         if (json.descriptions.length > 0)
         {
          //MAKE SURE TO EMPTY OUT DIV CLASSES FOR EACH TAB

            $(".description").empty();

            $.each(json.descriptions,function() 
            {
                    console.log("art method"+this['ID']);
                    $(".description").append(this['description']+this['ID']).hide().fadeIn("fast");
            });

        }
        }, 'json');
    });
};
```

When I `console.log(this['ID'])` in the `get_id()` method the correct value is displayed in the console, but when I `console.log("art method"+this['ID']` in the details method I get a value equal to the previously scrolled over thumbnail's ID. I'd really appreciate any insight on this issue.

Is it something to do with the use of `setTimeout()`? My code would not run without specifying a timeout for the method. For example if I load the page and then scroll over images with ID's 14 and then 13, my console will display:

```
14

13  
art method 14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are appending more of the same events. After the first mouseenter event occurs the details function is called, which then appends another mouseenter event. So subsequent calls will be doing the same thing. You can see an example of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/6qre72fk/.

```
var counter = 0;

$('#container1').on('mouseenter', function(){
  $('#container2').text('First mouseenter');
    appendingAnotherMouseEnter();
});

function appendingAnotherMouseEnter(){
  $('#container1').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('#container2').text(counter);
    counter++;
  });
}
```

You can see how the counter is incremented several times due to all appended the mouseenter events.

Comment: Dagojvg - thank you for responding. This solved my issue and I've marked your solution as the correct answer.